# Targeting divs inside a variable ID found using a class

Tags: jquery, variables, indexing, jquery-selectors

I need to add various IDs, an href, and data-parent attribute to a few elements inside div '**myId**' - of which I would like to return the ID of the div with the given class : `".template-none .section-accordion .accordion"`.

The snag here is that the system I am using is drag-and-drop, so these elements will be variable depending how many the user decides to add.  The ID for each element is created upon placement, but the class remains constant.

Now, these **are** inline, but upon checking appear to have an `index` of `-1`, which means they are likely not being seen as listed elements.  I have considering using the `.sibling` but struggled with implementation as I wouldn't know the ID until it was created.

I have it working currently, **but**, the jQuery I have below is taking the ID and index of the first item only and not styling each instance individually.  I know it's probably something very simple I have missed.

So, in summary, I would like to achieve:

1. Targeting all elements with the class "template-none .section-accordion .accordion", and returning the ID.
2. Using that now located variable ID, I would like to target the children elements .accordion, .accordion-toggle, and `.accordion-body` to add ID's and elements.
3. Ensure that each instance of `"template-none .section-accordion .accordion"` is styled relative to it's parent or as an individual item, and applying it to all instances of `"template-none .section-accordion .accordion"` instead of on a per-ID basis.

I hope that makes sense and really appreciate your input

Here's what I have so far:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    // sort accordions and add id's based on parents

    var index = jQuery( ".template-none section.section-accordion" ).index( this );

    var myId = jQuery(".template-none .section-accordion").prop("id");

    jQuery(".template-none .section-accordion .accordion").attr("id", myId + index)
    jQuery(".template-none .section-accordion .accordion-toggle").attr("data-parent", myId + index)

    jQuery(".template-none .section-accordion .accordion-body").attr("id", myId + index + 'body')
    jQuery(".template-none .section-accordion .accordion-toggle").attr("href", '#' + myId + index + 'body')

});
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle to also show your html markup? when reading 'dynamic' id's, i first think of event delegation. when a div doesn't exist on page load, a direct selector in js won't work, since it gets bound on page load. but if you wrap it inside a div, and select the wrapper, it would work. read more on this here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Interesting thank you I'll take a look and report back.  I can post the markup in a fiddle sure. http://jsfiddle.net/w1bg5gwq/ That's the result my current jQuery code gives.  Both different ID'd sections but the js applies the same to both, based on the first one.  There could be 10 more created underneath that would all need the same treatment dynamically. P.S note the returned index is -1.

Comment: Your example & JSFiddle are incomplete (e.g. there is no `.template-none` and the `index(this)` makes no sense as `this` is the `window` object there). Please provide the rest of the HTML and jQuery.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry, try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/w1bg5gwq/5/ It was incomplete as the first dude only asked for the HTML, but I take your point it's pretty unhelpful.  My issue is that the 'sections' shown there can be added by the user, so I cant forsee how many there will be, which is why I am trying to pull the ID from the class reference and use that.  The Section ID are randomly generated. Cheers

Comment: Looking at it now. Please note your nesting of divs is missing a few closing divs... Need to use clean formatting (TidyUp button in JSFiddle will help).

Comment: Sorry you're right, I have added and tidied here : http://jsfiddle.net/w1bg5gwq/6/

Comment: I have corrected the immediate issues and added some guidelines and  suggestions on how you might want to change it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the issues:

- You need each section to be processed in relation to itself as the current context. At the moment your code is passing `document` to `index` as that is the context of DOM ready.
- You have an id on a section starting with a `#` which is invalid.

Instead, iterate your sections (e.g. using `each`) and modify descendant elements *relative to that section* (e.g. using find from that section).

Example:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // sort accordions and add id's based on parents
    var index = jQuery(".template-none section.section-accordion").each(function (index) {
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).find(".accordion").attr("id", myId + index);
        $(this).find(".accordion-toggle").attr("data-parent", myId + index).attr("href", '#' + myId + index + 'body');
        $(this).find(".accordion-body").attr("id", myId + index + 'body');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w1bg5gwq/7/

**Notes:**

- `jQuery(function($){...});` is a handy shortcut for `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...});` that also supplies a local `$` variable so you can have shorter standard jQuery code.
- Although you are generating unique IDs on the descendant elements in each section, you will generally be better off working with classes.

Comment: Really helpful thanks for this @TrueBlueAussie, very much appreciated.  I had tried with the .each selector but hadn't considered using .find which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Very handy tips.  I appreciate your second bullet point about using classes, however the functionality of a Bootstrap accordion out of the box requires the ID's to link up correctly.  You'll be pleased to know this is working great with drag and drop now :)